# Differences between innerhtml and outerhtml

Tags: vb.net, innerhtml, outerhtml

I'm facing with an error that happens only sometimes:
I'm trying to check if a table (into a webpage) contains another table and to do this I look for tags `<table>` and `</table>` into `html` code.
Sometimes i get error while extracting innerhtml from the object that contains the main table (like it doesn't have an `innerhtml`).
So I tryed the code below and it seems that the problem is solved.

```
Try
    If mTables(1).innerhtml.contains("<table>") _
       AndAlso mTables(1).innerhtml.contains("</table>") Then
        'some code
    Else
        'some code
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Try
        If mTables(1).outerhtml.contains("<table>") _
           AndAlso mTables(1).outerhtml.contains("</table>") Then
        'some code
        Else
        'some code
        End If
    Catch ex2 As Exception
        'some code
    End Try
End Try
```

So my questions are:
1) what are the differences between `innerhtml` and `outerhtml`?
2) Do I have really solved? Or it seems to work but I haven't solved yet?
3) May I use `innertext` instead of `innerhtml`? Is it better?

**EDIT**
as I feared I still get errors, so now I'm trying with:

```
If mTables(1).getelementsbytagname("table").length > 0 then
...
```

But I'll be grateful if someone will explain me differences between `innerHtml` and `outerHtml`.

Comment: there is simple example who's show differences : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/DOM/Check/Find_out_the_difference_between_innerHTML_and_outerHTML_in_JavaScript.htm ... I'm not sure, but I think `innerText` is supported only by IE, equivalent for FF,chrome is `textContent` ... there is fiddle example showing differences between `innerHTML` and `textContent` (Your question no.3) : https://jsfiddle.net/k0fbdbar/

Comment: not sure, but try to use only code under `catch` (`outerhtml`).

Comment: @nelek Thanks for the link (I learnt something else but it don't seems to help me in this case). I tryed to use only `outerhtml` but I get errors sometimes: only way I found is in my question but I'm not sure of it because I don't really understan what I'm doing...